# JSR-303 Validation on sub-class

Tags: java, bean-validation

I have the following class structure

```
public Abstract class Person {
    private String fullName;
    private Address address;
    private Phone ;
}

class Staff extends Person{
    private String staffId;
}
```

I want to apply validation using JSR-303 on class Staff whereby Staff address and phone cannot have the value of null. However, I have some other classes that are class of Person where I don't wish to have the validation to be applied.

One way to do this that I could think of is by refactor Person and push the fields 'address' and 'phone' to Staff, but this means refactoring a lot of other classes (and not to mention redundancy this shall cause), and hence something I want to avoid.

Update.
I have changed Staff class, as follows

```
public class Staff extends Person {
    @NotNull
    private String staffEmploymentId;

    public String getStaffEmploymentId() {
        return staffEmploymentId;
    }

    public void setStaffEmploymentId(String id) {
        this.staffEmploymentId = id;
    }

    @Override
    @NotNull
    public void setPhones(List<Phone> phones) {
        super.phones = phones;
    }

    @Override
    @NotNull
    public void setAddress(Address a) {
        super.address = a;
    }

    @Override
    @NotNull
    public Address getAddress(){
        return super.address;
    }
}
```

However, I've got the following error.

```
javax.validation.ValidationException: Property setAddress does not follow javabean conventions.
```

I am using Apache BVal, as opposed to Hibernate Validator.

Answer (score 1):

Annotate getters instead of fields using annotations from JSR-330. 
You can override getters in `Stuff` and annotate them.

Comment: I tried this, and I got the following Exception: javax.validation.ValidationException: Property setAddress does not follow javabean conventions.

Comment: Make sure your accessor method signatures are `public Address getAddress()` and `public void setAddress(Address a)`.  You also may want to read the [Java Beans specification](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/7224-javabeans-1.01-fr-spec-oth-JSpec/), since it isn't very long.